# No output on complex Firebird queries in golang

Tags: go, firebird

I am currently working on a project to getting me started with golang / Firebird SQL and programming in general.

My Firebird SQL query works perfectly when run against the database:

| NAME | DELIVERY_DATE | LIST |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-06-19 19:00:00 | MEGAITEM groß STK:1 | SMALLITEM STK:1 | DELTAITEM klein STK:1 |
| NAME1 | 2021-06-19 12:00:00 | ITEM STK:1 |
| NAME2 | 2021-06-26 12:00:00 | ITEM STK:1 |
| NAME3 | 2021-06-18 17:00:00 | DELTATIEM STK:1 |

However, when I run it in my code, I get an empty array as an answer. The small Firebird query in the comments works fine. It returns three columns and the struct is filled up as expected.

Command line output:

```
2021/07/03 14:18:30 &{0xc000162000 0x55a4c0 0xc000106540 <nil> <nil> {{0 0} 0 0 0 0} false <nil> []}
2021/07/03 14:18:30 []
```

Golang Code

```golang
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    _ "github.com/nakagami/firebirdsql"
)

type SqlTableContent struct {
    UID  string
    DATE string
    NAME string
}

func main() {

    log.Println("Server started on: http://localhost:8080")
    http.HandleFunc("/", Mainquery)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)

}

func dbConn() (db *sql.DB) {
    db, err := sql.Open("firebirdsql", `SYSDBA:masterkey@localhost/C:\DATA.FDB`)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    return db
}

var tmpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("form/*"))

func Mainquery(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")

    db := dbConn()
    query := `with data as ( select article_name || ' STK:' || cast(quantity as integer) as quantity  , PREORDER_ID as PID from preorder_item )  SELECT PREORDER.NAME ,PREORDER.DELIVERY_DATE  ,LIST(DATA.QUANTITY, ' | ') FROM PREORDER INNER JOIN DATA ON PREORDER.ID = DATA.PID GROUP by PREORDER.NAME  ,PREORDER.DELIVERY_DATE`

    //  selDB, err := db.Query("SELECT SALE_ID, DELIVERY_DATE, NAME FROM PREORDER") This works
    selDB, err := db.Query(query)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    log.Println(selDB)
    var queryContent SqlTableContent
    var SqlTableContentArray []SqlTableContent
    for selDB.Next() {

        var id string
        var date string
        var name string

        err = selDB.Scan(&id, &date, &name)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }
        queryContent.UID = id
        queryContent.DATE = date
        queryContent.NAME = name

        SqlTableContentArray = append(SqlTableContentArray, queryContent)

    }
    tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "Show", SqlTableContentArray)
    log.Println(SqlTableContentArray)
    defer db.Close()
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the data exists in the database and is actually committed? As an aside, your query looks needlessly complex, and I think it should be possible to simplify it.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for the Input. I am quite sure the data exists because if i run the query manually against the DB it returns the data as described above. How would you go about making the query more simpler ?

Comment: If you're selecting in the same session and transaction that inserted the data, you can see (uncommitted) data that is not visible to other transactions. A simpler query would be `select NAME, DELIVERY_DATE, list(article_name || ' STK:' || cast(quantity as integer), ' | ') from PREORDER group by NAME, DELIVERY_DATE`

Comment: Are you sure the DSN is correct and the database can be queried? Maybe it's opening a new database instead of the one you are trying to get at? You might need some special escaping or something for windows file paths.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I belive you might not have the full picture here. I am joining two tables at one point. Take a look at this that is currently working for me ` with data as ( select article_name || ' STK:' || cast(quantity as integer) as quantity ,PREORDER_ID as PID from preorder_item ) SELECT PREORDER.NAME ,PREORDER.DELIVERY_DATE ,LIST(DATA.QUANTITY, ' | ') FROM PREORDER INNER JOIN DATA ON PREORDER.ID = DATA.PID GROUP by PREORDER.NAME ,PREORDER.DELIVERY_DATE `

Comment: Sorry, yes, I hadn't noticed that, though you could still get rid of the CTE I think. Unfortunately, I don't know go, so I can't help you further with that. If you have a reproducible example, you might want to consider posting to https://github.com/nakagami/firebirdsql/issues

Comment: Assuming u use Firebird 2.5+ use TraceAPI to check if the query ever arrived to the server  and if any rows were fetched or the query was closed without reading from it.  You can use CLI utility in the FIrebird folder, or IBExpert or http://FBProfiler.sf.net or any other